# Paralelismo com Angular 2

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2, typescript

Eu preciso inserir 30 mil registros no dispositivo (no SQLite) através de um arquivo. Mas no momento da inserção, a aplicação trava. Então eu pensei em criar um serviço assíncrono, mas eu não sei como fazer isso usando Angular 2.

**Código:**

```
this._http.get('assets/fishes.sql').subscribe(data => {

    var queries = data.text().split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        var currentQuery = queries[i];
        this.populaFishes(db, currentQuery);
    }
});
```

Como posso criar um serviço que rode em *background* para que a aplicação não trave usando Angular 2?

Comment: Você pretende rodar mais de uma vez esta tarefa? Ou somente no deploy? Qual é exatamente o caso de uso?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a melhor forma de fazer essa estrutura é enviar esses registros em quantidades menores, visto que quando você força a execução dessa inserção de 30 mil, você aloca todo esse conteúdo na memória (tendo em mente que você está criando algo para mobile).

O problema em questão não é do Angular, mas sim da capacidade de processamento. Você pode ter como exemplo do porque de não fazer isso quando vemos a API do Facebook. Independente se você quiser uma grande massa de dados, o facebook irá lhe enviar um limite de 5 mil registros.

Não só no angular mas em qualquer outra linguagem, uma manipulação massiva de dados vai requerer um grande processamento e (óbviamente) um consumo de memória, portanto é melhor você executar 30 vezes a sua função e dar a entrada de 1000 itens por vez do que executar 1 vez e dar entrada de tudo ao mesmo tempo, sem contar que, usando dessa forma, você ainda pode passar para o cliente um feedback do andamento do processamento (como uma barra de carregamento...)